# How can I access hidden dates on an archived website?

Tags: website

To preface this, I have absolutely zero knowledge in regards to programming. What I want to do is access the 17 dates that are not shown on this archived website: https://web.archive.org/web/20031002051647/http://www.avengedsevenfold.com:80/tourdates/tourdates.php (and the hidden dates on older/newer versions of this website, of course)

When I click on "Next" or "Show All Dates", it simply reloads the website. Is there a way to access the dates? I have skimmed through the source code, but didn't find anything. But the dates have to be somewhere, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not archived.

The Internet Archive does not have access to the server-side logic of a website and cannot fully replicate the behavior of dynamic pages (such as PHP in this case); the best it can do is to follow links and download each known URL as an independent, static page.

The crawler can follow and archive straightforward links such as `<a href="news.php?page=2">`. However, your website's "next"/"show all" **are not regular links** – they're an unholy combination of JavaScript actions and POST-based forms, either of which alone would have already made the crawler fail to recognize them as a link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="JavaScript:nextPage()"><img src=...></a>
```

Although the archiver can store a *copy* of the client-side JavaScript code, it does not interpret that code nor otherwise understand what nextPage() does here, and so must skip these JS-based buttons entirely. (You can see that IA [only has this one URL archived](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.avengedsevenfold.com:80/tourdates/*).)

(Even if the archiver could discover what the JS code does, it wouldn't be allowed to touch this specific form anyway – the usage of POST implies that each request may cause some changes on the server. Only GET requests are safe to crawl automatically.)

So when you click the "next" button, the browser still runs nextPage() and sends a request with page=2 or such, but there is no corresponding server-side code to process that request anymore – the Archive can only respond with the same static data as before.